# flutter - View a web page inside a container

Tags: flutter, dart, android-webview

I'm trying to create a master-detail type container starting with a column of ListTiles on the left side of the screen. When a user taps on an item, a preset URL will then be displayed on the rest of the screen. Tapping a different item displays a different preset URL.

I've looked at the Flutter [WebView Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) and and [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) packages, but either I don't understand them well enough (quite possible!) or they can't yet do everything I want them to to do.

Beside what I just mentioned, if possible I'd also like the web pages to open zoomed to fit the space they're in, but still be pinchable to other sizes.

p.s. I'm new to Flutter and am also confused about widget construction and memory management. If I try using something like a `WebView` widget, I don't know whether I just code a WebView widget every time I want to open a page, or if I somehow create a single WebView widget, add a `controller`, and code `.loadFromUrl()` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Row with two children. First children will be ListView that will be consisted of ListTiles. Second children will be the WebView. When a user taps on the list tile, load the url with the controller. There is no need to rebuild the WebView every time in your case

[image: example]

Example by using webview_flutter:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  WebViewController _controller;

  List pages = ["https://google.com", "https://apple.com"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: 300,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: pages.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(pages[index]),
                onTap: () {
                  if (_controller != null) {
                    _controller.loadUrl(pages[index]);
                  }
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: WebView(
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController c) {
              _controller = c;
            },
            initialUrl: 'https://stackoverflow.com',
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense, answers the question, and also deals with an issue I had trying on my own where I'd get an initial null exception.

Comment: This is a nice answer. I'll just mention in passing, though, that the resulting web pages will not be pinchable or zoomed to fit (as of Sep 2019).

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the webview inside a SizedBox

```
SizedBox(
   height: 300,
   child: WebView()
)
```